# remove HTML commands from string titanium

Tags: android, ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have string like this:

```
<div> This is a test </div>
```

How can i remove the `<div>` and `</div>` or other commands?

I have this for sum characters:

```
var FinalSTR = mySTR.replace(/<(?:.|)*?>/gm, '');
```

But it does not work for the commands that have `<>` or `</>` in the text

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all the tag with this command :

```
  var FinalSTR = mySTR.replace( /<[^>]+>/g, '' );
```

`[^>]` match a character that is not `>`
`[^>]+` match all consecutive characters that are not `>`
`<[^>]+>̀  match any tag

Answer (score 0):

Try following it may be work for you .

```
public String textFromHtml(String htmls) {
    return Html.fromHtml(htmls).toString();
}
```