# Removing special characters from .txt file give `LRB` , `LSB` , `RSB`, `LRB` , `RRB` etc. in Java

Tags: java, string, nlp, replaceall

I have a .txt file. Actually I got it from reading URL and converting HTML file. My .txt file contain so many special characters. I want to keep only English words. I used,

```
`String result = listOfWords.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+"," ");`
```

But, output replace some special characters as  `LRB` , `LSB` , `RSB` ,`LRB` ,  `RRB` like words.

Eg:

```
Eleanor (2008), Mathematics
```

`recent years. (TOP500 2006)^ Agatha C. Hughes (2000). Systems, Experts, and Computers. MIT Press. p. 161. ISBN 978-0-262-08285-3. The experience of SAGE helped make possible the first truly large-scale commercial real-time network: the SABRE computerized airline reservations system`

After replacing it gave result as,

```
 Eleanor  LRB     RRB    Mathematics
```

`recent years    LRB  TOP     RRB    Agatha C  Hughes  LRB     RRB    Systems   Experts   and Computers   MIT Press   p        ISBN       The experience of SAGE helped make possible the first truly large scale commercial real time network   the SABRE computerized airline reservations system`

How to solveenter code here this problem?

Comment: Sorry what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my example.

Comment: my very inefficient solution would split your string into an array of words and it would keep another array (or map, whatever) to keep track of what LRB/LSP/etc  were results from your translation. 

I know, this is a coward solution, but it could work :-)

Comment: Could you share your original text file which you got before you tried to split? Two or three lines will do.

Comment: What is you file encoding?

Comment: encoding is utf-8.

Comment: Are you think it was the problem with HTML parsing? So, Any special reference for HTML parsing?

Comment: Have you considered tokenizing your text using an open source tool such as NLTK or Stanford tagger? Then you can discard particular tags and don't have to worry about replacing non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex replacement only adds the big gaps (spaces). The LRB (Left Round Bracket) and RRB (Right Round Brackets) most likely come from any processing you do prior to the regex replacement. If you don't care about the special characters, you should probably remove them:

```
String result = listOfWords.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","");
```

As @Emalka mentioned, NLTK is a good source of [quick 'HOWTO'](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html). They are using `BeautifulSoup`. As your question talks about Java, there is a good answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149645/1013568) using [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org).

Comment: Yes, I used `Document Preprocessor` .It happened because of that. So, I avoid those words later using if Condition.