# Extract substring from string Android

Tags: java, android

I have string like this:

```
<a hidden="true" href="xxx" class=" zt-uie-session      </a>
```

How to extract href value in Android? It's string, not some object.

Comment: indexOf and substring

Comment: Is `hidden` and `class` always going to be there? Showing just one string isn't enough. Please show more examples of how the string can change, what format is the string in.

Comment: Please don´t use any kind of `String` functionallity.. If this tag isn´t really illformed as in your question just use [a html parse to do the job](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3149645/1799530)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Cgbxjy/1) to find href value:

```regex
href="([^"]*)"
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/bR4nmQ)

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("href=\"([^\"]*)\"").matcher("<a hidden=\"true\" href=\"xxx\" class=\" zt-uie-session      </a>");
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

**Output**

```
xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it is working fine

```
        String str = "<a hidden=\"true\" href=\"xxx\" class=\" zt-uie-session></a>";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(" (?:href)=\"([^\"]+)").matcher(str);

        while (m.find()) {
            String result = m.group(1);
            Log.d("HREF",": "+result); //result is "xxx" 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jsoup library for easily extract html attributes

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<a href='link' />");
Element link = doc.select("a").first();
return link.attr("href"); //xxx
```

Doc [here](https://jsoup.org/)