# display rich text in DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables, ckeditor, rich-text-editor, richtext

I want to display rich text in [DataTable](https://datatables.net/). The text is generated using [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/). My DataTable is getting rendered using jQuery:

```
var myTable = $("#_table").DataTable(this.properties);
```

I referred the official forum :[Editor: Display Rich Text in Datatable](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38221/editor-display-rich-text-in-datatable), the solution that was provided there was something in the lines of:

> This is probably caused by the [XSS protection](https://editor.datatables.net/manual/security#XSS) that is built into the Editor server-side libraries. If you are happy to allow scripting, you can disable that option.

But I do not know how to disable that property. I tried various methods but none worked.

**Edit 1:**
A snapshot of what the datatable displays now:
[image]

**Edit 2:**
In the datatable, text is displayed in string format: `"<p><h1>abc</h1></p>"` instead of `<p><h1>abc</h1></p>`.

Comment: What exactly do you get now in your datatables? Is the html code coming in datables correct? If the html code is stripped off any content then the problem lies with the editor. Perhaps a JSFIDDLE can shed some light...

Comment: @MaVRoSCy updated the text in the question...

Comment: Is the Rich text coming from your DB?

Comment: @annoyingmouse yes..

Comment: If you take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/ya20uqtg/ Airi has a bold Tokyo in her record... which sort of suggests that your issue shouldn't be an issue. Angelica has a whole chunk of markup on her record as well (with no line breaks). I'd perhaps take a look at the output from your DB again.

Comment: @annoyingmouse data generated by CKEditor is more than just simple HTML tags

Comment: @annoyingmouse I tried putting a dataset in the abobe fiddle and it does displays in the rtf. I don't know where I am going wrong

Comment: IN the datatable, text is displayed in string format: `"<p><h1>abc</h1></p>"` instead of `<p><h1>abc</h1></p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out why the datatable won't display data in rtf. Actully, CKEditor generates texts in two different formats:

1. `&lt;p&gt;&lt;s&gt;&lt;u&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;This is a custom defined task. Now there are further details:&lt;\/strong&gt;&lt;\/em&gt;&lt;\/u&gt;&lt;\/s&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;\n\n&lt;ul&gt;\n\t&lt;li&gt;&lt;span style=\"color:#00ff00\"&gt;&lt;s&gt;&lt;u&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span style=\"background-color:#ff0000\"&gt;List this is the first&lt;\/span&gt;&lt;\/strong&gt;&lt;\/em&gt;&lt;\/u&gt;&lt;\/s&gt;&lt;\/span&gt;&lt;\/li&gt;\n\t&lt;li&gt;&lt;span style=\"font-size:24px\"&gt;&lt;s&gt;&lt;u&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;This second.&lt;\/strong&gt;&lt;\/em&gt;&lt;\/u&gt;&lt;\/s&gt;&lt;\/span&gt;&lt;\/li&gt;\n\t&lt;li&gt;&lt;s&gt;&lt;u&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;span style=\"background-color:#00ff00\"&gt;And maybe a third&lt;\/span&gt;&lt;\/strong&gt;&lt;\/em&gt;&lt;\/u&gt;&lt;\/s&gt;&lt;\/li&gt;\n&lt;\/ul&gt;`

**HTML tags here are in the form of HTML entities.**

2. `"<p><s><u><em><strong>This is a custom goal having 3 parts:<\/strong><\/em><\/u><\/s><\/p>\n\n<ul>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:#0000cd\"><s><u><em><strong><span style=\"font-size:28px\"><span style=\"background-color:#ff8c00\">This is the first and the biggest.<\/span><\/span><\/strong><\/em><\/u><\/s><\/span><\/li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:#ff8c00\"><s><u><em><strong><span style=\"font-size:28px\"><span style=\"background-color:#0000cd\">This is the second amd tte<\/span><\/span><\/strong><\/em><\/u><\/s><\/span><\/li>\n\t<li><span style=\"font-size:26px\"><span style=\"color:#ff8c00\"><s><u><em><strong><span style=\"background-color:#0000cd\">yisohckdskcnk<\/span><\/strong><\/em><\/u><\/s><\/span><\/span><\/li>\n<\/ul>"`

**HTML tags here are parsed.**

Data is getting generated in both forms from the editor simultaneously. I am fetching data from the server using `jdbc` and parsing it using Jsoup ([Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string)).

In the default form, the second format gets rendered in rtf while the first format is encoded to HTML tags and the tags are rendered as text. By parsing once using `Jsoup`, the First format is encoded to HTML tags and is displayed as rtf while the second format is stripped of its tags and displayed as simple text without the HTML tags.

**So, this is actually an anomaly of the CKEditor (as it is generating text in two different formats) and not of the datatables.**

Comment: Nice one @HBK, glad you've got it sorted! :-)

Comment: @annoyingmouse :)