# Remove all the content of the html tag inside a string?

Tags: java, string

Hello to the community I have a query, it turns out that I have a string string, where I have html, I want to know an optimal way to remove the tag and content from the string string.

Original string

```
<div id=\"contentatt\">
 <div class=\"clearfix\"></div>
 <div class=\"mb-2\">
  <strong class=\"g2\"><a class=\"tombol-nightmode\">Night</a></strong> 
  <strong class=\"g2\"><a class=\"tombol-birumode\">Blue</a></strong> 
  <strong class=\"g2\"><a class=\"tombol-hijaumode\">Green</a></strong> 
  <strong class=\"g2\"><a class=\"tombol-pinkmode\">Pink</a></strong> 
  <strong class=\"g2\"><a class=\"tombol-kuningmode\">Yllw</a></strong> 
  <strong class=\"g2\"><a class=\"tombol-mediummode\"> - Med</a></strong> 
  <strong class=\"g2\"><a class=\"tombol-fontmode\"> - Big</a></strong>
 </div>
 <div class=\"clearfix\"></div>
 <h1 class=\"title\">I'm Really A Superstar - Chapter Prologue</h1>
 <div class=\"clear\"></div>
</div>
```

The issue is that I need to extract and remove all the div chain located by the class **mb-2** (`<div class=\"mb-2\">`), and only the rest the following way is wanted.

```
<div id=\"contentatt\">
 <div class=\"clearfix\"></div>
 <div class=\"clearfix\"></div>
 <h1 class=\"title\">I'm Really A Superstar - Chapter Prologue</h1>
 <div class=\"clear\"></div>
</div>
```

I hope you have understood what I require.
Regards,

Comment: You can easily do this with jsoup. I can post an answer with code if you are having trouble with the api

Comment: Did you try anything already? Why did it not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your particular example you can try something like this:

```
public static String removeBetween(String inputString, String startString, String endString) {
    int startIndex = inputString.indexOf(startString);
    int endIndex = inputString.indexOf(endString, startIndex + 1) + endString.length();
    String resultString;
    if (startIndex == 0) {
        resultString = inputString.substring(endIndex+1);
    }
    else {
        String a =  inputString.substring(0 , startIndex - 1);
        String b =  inputString.substring(endIndex).trim();
        resultString = a + b;
    }
    return resultString;
}
```

The code above assumes each line within your html string ends with a newline tag (\n). This may not be exactly what you are looking for but it at least provides a concept to play with. Running your example html string through this method returns a string that would provide a printed console output of:

```
<div id="contentatt">
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
 <h1 class="title">I'm Really A Superstar - Chapter Prologue</h1>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the elements using javascript after loading the page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language='javascript'>
        function removeDivElements(){
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if( x[i].className == "mb-2" ){
                    x[i].outerHTML = "";
                    delete x[i];
                }
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contentatt">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="mb-2">
          <strong class="g2"><a class="tombol-nightmode">Night</a></strong> 
          <strong class="g2"><a class="tombol-birumode">Blue</a></strong> 
          <strong class="g2"><a class="tombol-hijaumode">Green</a></strong> 
          <strong class="g2"><a class="tombol-pinkmode">Pink</a></strong> 
          <strong class="g2"><a class="tombol-kuningmode">Yllw</a></strong> 
          <strong class="g2"><a class="tombol-mediummode"> - Med</a></strong> 
          <strong class="g2"><a class="tombol-fontmode"> - Big</a></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <h1 class="title">I'm Really A Superstar - Chapter Prologue</h1>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
//call after page loaded
window.onload=removeDivElements;
</script>
</html>
```