# ireport - list style type="square" doesn't work

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a requirement where to enable list with square bullets in ireport.

I used below coding and set markup as "html" but don't know how to achieve this.

```
"Names of fruits are:" +
"<ul style = {margin-top=-13px; list-style-type=square;} >" +
"<li> &nbsp; &nbsp;Apple</li>" +
"<li> &nbsp; &nbsp;Orange</li>" +
"<li> &nbsp; &nbsp;Banana</li>" +
"</ul>"
```

entered above code in Text Field Expression of iReport. When I compiled **No Error**. When I do preview, the list comes with bullets of disc not square. Besides, have to reduce the gap between ul & li which occurs default. Anyone knows the solution, pls help with coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Unsupported elements

The `<ul>` and `<ol>` elements are [not supported](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/styledtext/index.html):

> The JasperReports proprietary markup language is called styled text and is an XML based format in which the style of any portion of text inside a text element can be changed by embedding that portion inside a `<style>` tag or other simple HTML tag from the following list:
>
> ```
> <b>
> <u>
> <i>
> <font>
> <sup>
> <sub>
> <li>
> <br>
> ```
>
> The `<style>` tag has various attributes for altering the color, font, or other style properties of the text. From the standard HTML `<font>` tag, only the fontFace, color, and size attributes are recognized by the JasperReports engine. Each individual style property is inherited from the overall text element or from the parent `<style>` tag when nested `<style>` tags are used.

## Solution #1 - Structured data

Instead of including an HTML blurb directly in the report, consider querying the data from the data source directly. For example, consider the following table in the database, with a name of `Fruits`:

```
| fruits |
|--------|
| Apple  |
| Orange |
| Banana |
```

Such as:

```sql
SELECT fruit_name FROM fruits;
```

Then change the presentation logic in the report:

```xml
<detail>
    <band height="15">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="10" height="15" />
            <text><![CDATA[■]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="11" y="0" width="50" height="15"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fruit_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

## Solution #2 - Parsed data

If the input string must be a simple HTML document (an idea that mixes presentation with content, an unfortunate coupling), then another possibility is:

1. Convert the HTML to a [plain text string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149645/59087).
2. Convert that string into structured string of data (e.g., put each line in double quotes then join all newlines with a comma).
3. Convert the structured string to a [JR data source](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html) (e.g., [JRCsvDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRCsvDataSource.html)).
4. Pass the JR data source into a subreport.
5. Revise the detail band of the subreport as shown in the first solution.

## Addendum

There are other possibilities, but the underlying problem is that the data (i.e., the HTML string) is providing two different functions: (1) how the data appears with (2) the data to be displayed. To solve this problem in the most flexible way, separate how the data must appear from the data itself. That is, don't pass preformatted HTML into a report.