# Strip string of hml tags in play framework

Tags: java, html, playframework, escaping, playframework-2.5

Is there a clever way to **strip a string from all html tags in Play Framework** (Java)? An alternative is to use tools like e.g. jSoup or regex, as suggested in [Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string)
, but doesn't Play Framework offer something that can do this as well?

For example, the string:

```
<div>Testing/div>
```

should become:

```
Testing
```

I thought *HtmlFormat.escape(string).text()* did exactly this, but it doesn't seem to effect the string at all.

*HtmlFormat.escape(string).body()* and *HtmlFormat.escape(string).toString()* replaces all html special characters with entity names (e.g. "*<*" is replaced by "*&lt;*"), but there is no point in doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

Comment: This question revolves around whether it's possible to strip tags from a String in Play Framework or not. [Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string) gives alternative solutions, should it not be possible to do it in Play Framework.

Comment: There is no such thing in Play and JSoup is the way to go here (simple and easy to integrate).