# Better way to remove HTML tags in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, replace

I have a `comments` column and the comments added to release are stored as rich text in `comments` column. Now i'm trying to process this data and get an human readable output. I'm providing 2 sample `comment` data i have in my `oracle SQL` db which i'm trying to process.

Example 1 :

```
    <html>
<body>
<div align="left"><font face="Arial Unicode MS"><span style="font-size:8pt">Display the frulog on the count values</span></font></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example 2: `<not implemented in this release>`

i used the below query to process the html characters

```
Select (REGEXP_REPLACE(comments),'<.+?>') from test_table;
```

Note: consider values provided in Example 1 and Example 2 are passed in as column `comments` in the above SQL command.

the query result for `Example 1` was `Display the frulog on the count values` which is what i'm expecting. result for `Example 2` was `''`. Value in `Example 2` was not an html tag but it still replaced the tags. How can i make the replace statement smart.

Feel free to drop your suggestions .

Comment: Maybe [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/bGp2HO/2)? It can be used as `REGEX_REPLACE(comments, regex, '', 1, 0, 'in')`

Comment: Seems to be a frequent question without a clear answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string

Answer (score 3):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f013/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE comments ( value ) AS
SELECT '<html>
<body>
<div align="left">
<font face="Arial Unicode MS">
<span style="font-size:8pt">
  Display the frulog on the count values
</span>
</font>
</div>
</body>
</html>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '<not implemented in this release>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '<test a="1"
  b=''2''
  c = 3
  d
  e = ">" >test</test>' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '\s*</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(".*?"|''.*?''|[^''">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>\s*',
         NULL,
         1,
         0,
         'im'
       ) AS replaced
FROM   comments
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f013/3/0)**:

```
|                                    VALUE |                               REPLACED |
|------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------|
| <html>                                   | Display the frulog on the count values |
| <body>                                   |                                        |
| <div align="left">                       |                                        |
| <font face="Arial Unicode MS">           |                                        |
| <span style="font-size:8pt">             |                                        |
| Display the frulog on the count values   |                                        |
| </span>                                  |                                        |
| </font>                                  |                                        |
| </div>                                   |                                        |
| </body>                                  |                                        |
| </html>                                  |                                        |
|------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------|
| <not implemented in this release>        |                                 (null) |
|------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------|
| <test a="1"                              |                                   test | 
|   b='2'                                  |                                        |
|   c = 3                                  |                                        |
|   d                                      |                                        |
|   e = ">" >test</test>                   |                                        |
```

*Note: `<not implemented in this release>` is a valid HTML [custom element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements) with tag name `not` and attributes `implemented`, `in`, `this` and `release`.*

If you only want to replace specific HTML elements then list them at the start of the regular expression:

```
\s*</?(a|abbr|acronym|address|applet|area|article|aside|audio|b|base|basefont|bdi|bdo|bgsound|big|blink|blockquote|body|br|button|canvas|caption|center|cite|code|col|colgroup|command|content|data|datalist|dd|del|details|dfn|dialog|dir|div|dl|dt|element|em|embed|fieldset|figcaption|figure|font|footer|form|frame|frameset|h1|head|header|hgroup|hr|html|i|iframe|image|img|input|ins|isindex|kbd|keygen|label|legend|li|link|listing|main|map|mark|marquee|menu|menuitem|meta|meter|multicol|nav|nextid|nobr|noembed|noframes|noscript|object|ol|optgroup|option|output|p|param|picture|plaintext|pre|progress|q|rp|rt|rtc|ruby|s|samp|script|section|select|shadow|slot|small|source|spacer|span|strike|strong|style|sub|summary|sup|table|tbody|td|template|textarea|tfoot|th|thead|time|title|tr|track|tt|u|ul|var|video|wbr|xmp)((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(".*?"|''.*?''|[^''">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>\s*
```