# How to remove html tags changed this Unicode of xml changed as String in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I received xml from the server. 
xml's content is just book's description. It has html tags in content. To show this as smartly, I hope to remove this all. 
How can I this remove?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string)