# java replace between two tags html with case sensitive

Tags: java, regex

I have this Regex code in java that removes `<style>` tag from a string:

```
  String questionDroz  = "TEST0 <style>TESTE1</style> <style attr='attr1'>TEST2</style> <STYLE>TEST3</STYLE>";
  System.out.println(questionDroz.replaceAll("(?s)<style>.*?</style>", ""));
```

Output

```
TEST0  <style attr='attr1'>TEST2</style> <STYLE>TEST3</STYLE>
```

I want to remove also style with atributes, can be any atribute in tag, and dont have case sensitive.

the result must be only:

```
TEST0
```

Also if possible add `<script>` in this regex, or I can do this separately in another regex no problem.

Comment: You can add `i` flag, and match attributes with `[^>]*`: `.replaceAll("(?si)<style(?:\\s[^>]*)?>.*?</style>", "")`

Comment: Every time that you see HTML and Regex in the same sentence, think about this [Amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3111149)

Comment: thanks!!! everyone!!

Comment: Have a look at [this answer by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149645/11046661).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not consider using a HTML parser as an option, or this is a one-off job involving the HTML content that you have control of, you can use either of

```java
String regex = "(?si)\\s*<style(?:\\s[^>]*)?>.*?</style>";
String regex = "(?i)\\s*<style(?:\\s[^>]*)?>[^<]*(?:<(?!/style>)[^<]*)*</style>";
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/z8i6w7/2/) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/z8i6w7/3). Note the second one is more efficient and should be preferred with long inputs.

*Details*

- `(?si)` - `Pattern.DOTALL` (`s`) and `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` embedded flag options
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `<style` - literal text
- `(?:\s[^>]*)?` - an optional sequence of a whitespace and then any zero or more chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>` char
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `[^<]*(?:<(?!/style>)[^<]*)*` - any zero or more chars other than `<` and then any zero or more repetitions of a `<` not followed with `/style>` and then any zero or more chars other than `<`
- `</style>` - a literal text.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/lNwi0n):

```java
String questionDroz  = "TEST0 <style>TESTE1</style> <style attr='attr1'>TEST2</style> <STYLE>TEST3</STYLE>";
String regex = "(?si)<style(?:\\s[^>]*)?>.*?</style>";
System.out.println(questionDroz.replaceAll(regex, "").trim());
// => TEST0
```

Comment: awesome, thaks alot!

Comment: is possible to add and operator or.. like or button or script?

Comment: @sealabr Replace `<style` with `<(style|button)` and all the rest occurrences of `style` with `\\1`, i.e. `String regex = "(?si)<(style|button)(?:\\s[^>]*)?>.*?</\\1>";` or `String regex = "(?i)\\s*<(style|button)(?:\\s[^>]*)?>[^<]*(?:<(?!/\\1>)[^<]*)*</\\1>";`