# Get a Thymeleaf template fragment in Java

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a template :

```
<div th:fragment="subject">
    [[${var1}]] -  blabla
</div>
<div th:fragment="body">
titi
</div>
```

In Java :

I want to retrieve only the subject fragment and put it in a variable.

```
String subject =  templateEngine.process(template.getPath()+" :: subject", context);
```

but I got the error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClassLoader resource "mail/templates/mail_depot.html :: subject" could not be resolved
```

I can successfully call:

```
String subject =  templateEngine.process(template.getPath(), context);
```

but when I add " :: subject" to only retrieve the subject fragment I got an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TemplateEngine` has different versions of the `process()` method. The one you need is:

```java
public final String process​(String template, Set<String> templateSelectors, IContext context)
```

This method takes a set of strings, where each string can be the name of a fragment.

For example:

```java
Set<String> selectors = new HashSet<>();
selectors.add("subject");

String subject =  templateEngine.process(template.getPath(), selectors, context);
```

In your case, this will return a string containing:

```
<div>
    ??? -  blabla
</div>
```

But with the `???` replaced by whatever value `[[${var1}]]` resolves to.

---

See the [`TemplateEngine` JavaDoc](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.15.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/TemplateEngine.html#process(java.lang.String,org.thymeleaf.context.IContext)) for more details.

---

**Update**

Follow-up related question: If you want to directly access the content of the fragment, excluding the enclosing HTML tags, you can use the following:

```
<th:block th:fragment="subject">
    foo
</th:block>
<div th:fragment="body">
    bar
</div>
```

The Thymeleaf [`<th:block>`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#synthetic-thblock-tag) tag removes itself.

If you have nested tags inside your fragment, those will not be removed if you use `<th:block>`.

Otherwise, use an HTML parser such as Jsoup:

```
Jsoup.parse(yourHtmlString).text()
```

Comment: thanks, what would be the easiest way to get only "??? -  blabla" whithout the html tags ?

Comment: I would recommend using an HTML parser for that. For example, Jsoup - something like `Jsoup.parse(yourHtmlString).text()`. You may see a lot of examples which suggest using regular expressions, but I would stay away from those, personally.

Comment: [Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240546/12567365) - and probably various similar questions, if you dig around.

Comment: ok, I just wanted to know if there was a way to retrieve only the content of the fragment without the html tag surrounding but looks like the answer is no.

Comment: I misunderstood - I added a note to the answer about that. But I think an HTML parser is still the way to go.